# php decode json recibido mediante _POST

Tags: php, json, post

Tengo el siguiente caso:
Recibo una variable _POST que trae dos datos en formato JSON y necesito sólo tomar uno de esos datos.
Intento con esto, pero el resultado es NULL.
Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias

```html
<?php
    $CuentasBancariasSel=$_POST["CuentasBancariasSel"]; //Recibo: array(1) { [557]=> string(33) "{'id_cuenta':'1','id_banco':'39'}" } 
    $obj = json_decode($CuentasBancariasSel);
    $CuentasBancariasSelOK = $obj->{'id_cuenta'};
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el json que estás enviando a ese archivo .php? Podría ser un string no válido, la función json_decode devuelve NULL si el argumento no se puede decodificar.

Comment: puedes intentar imprimir con un var_dump() el json que recibes. y después de que lo pasas por el json_decode volverlo a imprimir. Muchas veces lo que pasa es que las llaves cambian, para acceder al campo podría ser, $CuentasBancariasSel['id_cuenta']; por que el echo de que estés decodificando un json no quiere decir que tengas un objeto.

Comment: Modifiqué el código (también en la pregunta de este post), pero sigo sin lograrlo. Aparentemente no encuentra objeto. 
El json que envío es un value de un option: <option value="{'id_cuenta':'1','id_banco':'39'}">BANCO XX</option>
El primer var_dump me dice: `array(1) { [560]=> string(33) "{'id_cuenta':'1','id_banco':'39'}" } `
Después del json_decode el var_dump es NULL.

Comment: $CuentasBancariasSelOK = $obj->$id_cuenta;

Comment: @EduBw También es NULL.

Comment: $obj = json_decode($CuentasBancariasSel,true);

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución. Dejo el código:
Debí parsear el array y reemplazar las comillas simples por dobles.

Sugerencia: Estén siempre atentos a las comillas porque dan mucho dolor de cabeza.
Saludos!

```html
<?php
$CuentasBancariasSel=$_POST["CuentasBancariasSel"];
foreach($CuentasBancariasSel as $CuentasBancarias){
$arr=str_replace("'","\"",$CuentasBancarias); 
$obj = json_decode($arr);
$CuentaBancaria = $obj->{"id_cuenta"};
}
?>
```